# How add variable to django request from my front-end?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am developing web app, with djangorestframework on the back and Vue.js on the front. Interface was translated to a few language. On the site footer user can see icons of language represented country flag.
After hit the need icon, app translate all text to required language. All actions for translate do in front and my backend know nothing about what is language was chosen. Now I want to tell my back-end about chosen language, how can I do it? I think to add a variable language to my django request object, but I can find nothing about it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified a language variable in my localStorage then I returned value to Content-Language header and after this I've could take the language value in my django request.

Answer (score 0):

I see two approach :

- Send the language value on every (interesting) request, as you proposed
- Or, keep it in user settings in the backend : you add a charfield on [a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). When you need the language value during a request, you can access it through `self.request.user.lang`. You will have to add a route to update the value when users click on the icons.

It depends on how usual the language value is needed ; if its often, it will be simpler to have it in the backend. But you must keep the value up to date... Its a trade off :)